# Get-Date from variable in the format of "ddd mmm dd HH:MM:SS yyyy"

Tags: datetime, powershell-2.0

I am writing a script to email specific people based on errors in an error log. I am doing this in specific intervals and am trying to write a compare function.

Before I do this, however, I will need to pull the date out of the error logs. The first 24 characters of each line in the error log is a date, in the format of `ddd mmm dd HH:MM:SS yyyy`. I have been able to parse (using the `Substring()` method) the first 24 characters out of the error line.

what my end goal is, is to compare each date in each line in the error log, with a dynamic date value, to find where the last time the script ran left off.

**Edit:** my question is how do I get a string that is in a variable, into a date format that I can then compare against.

I cant seem to get anything to work, the string that is in the variable (for troubleshooting purposes) is Mon Aug 24 21:01:52 2015

Comment: So what is the question? This just lists what you've done.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my questions to actually have one! Sorry about that

Comment: http://winpowershell.blogspot.com/2006/09/systemdatetime-parseexact.html

Comment: This doesnt seem to work @JoelCoehoorn , I am trying to use a variable rather than a "string"

Comment: "Can't seem to get anything to work" is an insufficient problem description. Show your code, show an input sample, and describe how *exactly* you "can't get it to work".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 2 options:

1. Format your reference date accordingly and compare that string to the substring extracted from the log:

   ```psh
   $fmt = 'ddd mmm dd HH:MM:SS yyyy'
   $refdate = Get-Date -f $fmt
   if ($refdate -eq $dateFromLog) { ... }
   ```
2. Parse the strings from the log into actual dates and compare them to the reference date:

   ```psh
   $fmt = 'ddd mmm dd HH:MM:SS yyyy'
   $refdate = Get-Date
   $culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
   $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateFromLog, $fmt, $culture)
   if ($refdate -eq $date) { ... }
   ```

Comment: I think I will need to compare the dates, because I cant use the -eq as there might not be an exact match, I am just trying to go back approx 30 minutes or so each time

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, so

```
$file = 'Mon Aug 24 21:01:52 2015 blah blah blah blah blah'
$test = $file.Substring(0,24)
$DateString = $test.toString()
$theDTString = "Mon Aug 24 21:01:52 2015".toString()
$theDateTimeObject = ([datetime]::ParseExact($DateString,"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",$null))
```

works, my issue was that I had the three "m"s as lowercase which (I should have known) matters. I was rushing through real quick so that was my bad guys. Thanks for all of your help